# Unity panel menus only work on one monitor of dual monitor setup

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, panel, menu

I have just installed 11.10 on my dual monitor system, I have a problem with the panel menus (settings/power, memenu, calendar etc.).

What is happening is on one monitor, everything functions fine, but on the other, the menus do not stay open when I click on them.  The will appear briefly, but then close straight away.  If I click and hold they stay open, but only until I let go.

Like I said, this only happens on one monitor at a time, but the monitor on which it happens seems to change.

**EDIT:**

OK it seems there is a bug filed for this here: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/869196) (thanks Adrian).  Still no fix out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug report out for this one already

[Launchpad bug #869196](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/869196)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I file a bug report?

Search for one first but if you can't find one, the answer should always be ***YES!***

Comment: That was what I first thought, but using ubuntu-bug, they recommended I seek technical support before filing a bug :S